# How to plot only the max Y-value for each corresponding x-value

Tags: excel, graph, max

I have data where there are multiple values for a single date. I want to plot only the max Y-value for each given date. Here is my full data set (I am plotting Date (X) vs Cumulative PnL (Y)):
[image]

And here is my current graph:
[image]

I want to make it such that only the maximum Y-value is used for each X-value, such that there are no vertical line son the graph. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Standard charting is very limited when you want to manipulate the data.
I recommend to create a Pivot Table and change the Value Field Setting to "MAX", this will show only the max value for duplicate dates. Now you can plot without the spike lines.